# Unable to compute average time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

3 days old into MongoDB, and I am not finding it very fluid. I am simply trying to compute the average time for a field but I keep running into all sorts of problems.

Here is my code:

```
db.results.group({
     key:{"profile.Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket::read==>fgets":{$exists:true}},
     initial: {count: 0, total:0},
     reduce: function(doc, out){ 
         out.count++; 
         out.total += doc."profile.Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket::read==>fgets.wt";
     },
     finalize: function(out){
            out.avg = out.total/out.count;
     }
});
```

The error:

**SyntaxError: Unexpected String**

The above is a very childish error, but I can't understand why it would state this, the only plausible reason I can think of is that the keys I have specified here are in quotes hence Mongo is getting confused.

BUT, these keys ARE in quotes in my collection, so there should be no reason why I keep getting this syntax error right ?

Sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532a2a986803faba658b456b"),
    "profile" : {
        "main()==>register_shutdown_function" : {
            "ct" : 1,
            "wt" : 13,
            "cpu" : 0,
            "mu" : 1568,
            "pmu" : 1000
        },
        "main()==>load::htdocs/index.php" : {
            "ct" : 1,
            "wt" : 17,
            "cpu" : 0,
            "mu" : 1736,
            "pmu" : 4296
},
        {"Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl::write==>curl_exec" : {                                           
            "ct" : 3,
            "wt" : 54782314,
            "cpu" : 16001,
            "mu" : 83288,
            "pmu" : 49648
        }, ....
```

Comment: can you post a sample document from the collection?

Comment: Haven't worked with Mongo, but if that's Javascript, then it should be out.total += doc["profile.Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket::read==>fgets.wt"]; In JS, object keys can be strings, but they have to be looked up using bracket not dot syntax.

Comment: @AnandJayabalan just did.

Comment: You are better off using the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).  I was typing a sample query, but Neil beat me to it :)  Look at his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment your problem is one of forming valid JavaScript. Also your "key" value would not seem to be what you really want. There is however the [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) function that you should be favoring over the use of "group"

```js
db.results.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$and": [
            { "profile.Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket::read==>fgets.wt": {
                "$exists": true 
            }},
            { "profile.Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket::read==>fgets.wt": { 
               "$not": { "$type": 2 }
            }}
        ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "total": { "$sum": 
            "$profile.Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket::read==>fgets.wt"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "avg": { "$divide": [ "$total", "$count" ] }
   }}
])
```

The aggregation pipeline sort of supercedes earlier introduced functions such as `group` and `distinct`. And for all but trivial operations *should* be your favored choice.

It will run much faster as well as this is processed in native code and not the JavaScript engine.

Also see the [SQL to aggregation mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the documentation.

## Problems With Data

Your sample is not very complete. To sort out all issues I have to put in a document like this:

```
{
    "profile": {
        "Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket::read==>fgets": {                                           
            "ct" : 3,
            "wt" : 54782314,
            "cpu" : 16001,
            "mu" : 83288,
            "pmu" : 49648
        },
    }
}
```

Also your document example has some invalid fields in it:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532a2a986803faba658b456b"),
    "profile" : {
        "main()==>register_shutdown_function" : {
            "ct" : 1,
            "wt" : 13,
            "cpu" : 0,
            "mu" : 1568,
            "pmu" : 1000
        },
        "main()==>load::htdocs/index.php" : { <-- Invalid
            "ct" : 1,
            "wt" : 17,
            "cpu" : 0,
            "mu" : 1736,
            "pmu" : 4296
},
```

So that field cannot exist as it has a `.` in the field name, which for obvious *sub-document* reasons is not allowed.

Comment: thanks, I literally copy pasted your code, it says:
"exception: the group aggregate field name '$count' cannot be an operator name"

Comment: ok, I took it out, but this time it gives me "avg":null as the answer

Comment: removed the $count and replaced it with count, gave me an avg as 0? that's coz it looks like the total is 0

Comment: @ParijatKalia Right you are typing error by me that time. Corrected.

Comment: thanks. It does the count correctly (74) but not the total, hence the avg comes out as 0 as well,

Comment: @ParijatKalia You might have some inconsistencies in your data. See the updated arguments in $match and possibly even try those (or the reverse) using find as there may be missing keys or string values.

Comment: not sure i followed your latest edit clearly, right now I am trying to fix it's syntax errors, Hopefully I will get that

Comment: @ParijatKalia Not a great morning for me. That is corrected. The main problem I have as would others is that your "example document" still does not show this key value that you are using. So this is guessing somewhat. That point is that is trying to make sure that the values you are trying to "sum" actually exist and that they are at least not strings.

Comment: oh, this key exists, the example document is only a small sample, it's a huge JSON file. I ran your latest query after some syntax ( there is a [ bracket after $and: ) and I get 
exception: $and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array

Comment: I think it has something to do with referencing the key value for the total

Comment: I fixed it, thanks so much for your answer, I am marking it as correct since it lead me to the solution and I'll provide my answer as well

Comment: @ParijatKalia After actually having to reconstruct your data myself the corrections are in there. You should also pay attention to the problems with how you have presented the data as shown in additional information.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks for your help, the data I provided was only an initial sample

Comment: @ParijatKalia For reference see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But still, you are doing well 3 days in to digest this.

Answer (score 0):

@Neils answer led me to the correct solution:

```
db.results.aggregate([
    {
       $match: {
            "profile.Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket::read==>fgets.wt": {
                "$exists": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": null,
            "total": {
                $sum: "$profile.Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket::read==>fgets.wt"
            },
            "count": {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "count": "$count",
            "avg": {
                $divide: [
                    "$total",
                    "$count"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: just a suggestion... if you want the average, you could directly use the `$avg` operator rather than dividing it manually using `$divide`.